# Como otimizar queries SQL contendo DELETE relacionado com SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_items where page_id='84'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($a)){
    $base_item = $row['item_ids'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM items_rooms where base_item = '".$base_item."'")  
or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Como posso executar esse script em `PHP` apenas com querys em mysql?
Estou tendo problemas no php com `TIMEOUT`, então pensei em executar no mysql direto, só não sei como...

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow-pt. Você pode perguntar em português aqui Lucas, poderia [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/55527/edit) a sua pergunta e traduzi-la?

Comment: obrigado pela informação, você sabe como me ajudar? traduzi

Comment: Provavelmente não é isto que queres... num terminal executa `php myscript`.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo o que entendi você quer otimizar o script e obviamente a performance.
Realmente não é necessário dar toda essa volta.

Veja um exemplo de DELETE com JOIN.

```
DELETE `items_rooms` FROM `items_rooms` AS T1 LEFT JOIN `catalog_items` AS T2
ON T2.item_ids = T1.base_item
WHERE T2.page_id='84'
```

Recomendo que faça backup antes de executar pois não posso garantir a integridade disso por ser alheio a estrutura do seu sistema. Mas acredito que não deve causar nenhum problema.

Também não garanto que aumentará a performance. Isso depende do estado das estruturas, índices, chaves, etc.

Há outros meios de resolver como pelo uso de select múltiplo. Se esse exemplo acima não mudar muito a performance, procure testar outros meios, rever como está a estrutura de dados, etc.

Uma observação, em versões antigas do MySQL, o uso do alias em expressões DELETE não eram reconhecidas. Mas não lembro no momento qual versão. Algo próximo ao 5.3 ou 5.1.

Comment: Isso realmente pode ajudar diminuindo o tempo de processamento pela pela metade.

Answer (score 2):

O quer você pode fazer é aumentar o tempo limite do processamento do PHP. Antes deste processamento adicione com a função `set_time_limit($tempo)`
.

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); //para um tempo infinito

set_time_limit($segundos); // o tempo que vc quizer em segundos
```

Answer (score 1):

A seguinte query te dará o mesmo resultado (supondo que o nome dos campos da sua tabela estejam consistentes):

```
DELETE FROM items_rooms where base_item IN 
(SELECT base_item FROM catalog_items where page_id='84')
```

A query irá excluir de uma lista de `base_item` que foi selecionada dentro do `SELECT` e nem precisa do PHP para ser executada.